# Night light sunrise/sunset not working

Tags: settings, release-juno, nightlight

After a new clean installation of Juno I tried to enable Night light with the automatic sunrise/sunset timing. This did not work as expected. What did happen was, that night light kicked in only at the (previously) designated manual times. You can try to switch to manual and change the times, and this setting will stick even after changeing the switch to "sunrise/sunset".

There is a similar problem with Ubuntu that I know of - if a user selects the same option in gnome-settings, but does not enable Location services (in a separate settings panel), the functionality won't work. Unfortunately enabling location services in elementary switchboard doesn't solve this issue in eOS. This should be addressed by the devs.

Comment: Please add the solution separately by posting it as an answer.

Comment: And please mark your answer as one to let others know that the answer actually solved your problem.

Comment: I will, but I can't at the moment - I will only get a message about having to wait for two days...

Comment: Yes, system requires a minimum wait time before a answer can be marked as an answer. I forgot to tell this earlier, my bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an interim solution you can install *dconf-editor* and change the key `org/gnome/system/location` to enabled. After that, the Night light settings will work as expected.

You can also change the setting in the terminal without installing anything by executing `gsettings set org.gnome.system.location enabled true`

Please execute `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor` in the terminal to install *dconf-editor*. You can also find it in the AppCenter.

Answer (score 1):

Is is also necessary to change a line in

```
/etc/geoclue/geoclue.conf
```

change this line:

```
url=https://location.services.mozilla.com/v1/geolocate?key=99054b086f8a4b9fa033e4a75801ab52
```

to this:

```
url=https://location.services.mozilla.com/v1/geolocate?key=geoclue
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. But for me this was already correct.